# The type of expression must be an array but resolved to list<string>

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I am creating a list of string fields and storing in a array list. Now  when passing that array list to the array I am getting the following error :

The type of expression must be an array but resolved to list

```
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
        fields.add("_raw");
        //fields.add("_time");
        fields.add("host");
        fields.add("sourcetype");
        fields.add("source");
        jobRes.setFieldList(fields[]);
        jobRes.setOffset(2500);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little vague. Is this java? C#? At any rate, I'd bet the problem is in your cast. I'd try something like:

```
jobRes.setFieldList(fields.ToArray(new String[fields.Size()])
```

This will actually pass an array.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for the addtl answer, I can't flippin' comment) On second glance, I'd imagine this is Java, since C# doesn't have an ArrayList that allows type assignments (I don't think, anyway). The above is actually correct in Java, since ArrayList inherits from abstract list. The reason for this is usually to convert to simplify iteration/conversion. ArrayList already has an add method, so it looks like the cast is there only to enable a different cast that isn't being performed... :)